# Wrong page number and bookmark for Bibliography chapter

Tags: bibliographies, page-numbering, bookmarks

I have a problem with a specific `\documentclass[]{report}`: in the ToC, both the bookmark and the page number for the Bibliography chapter are incorrect, as they point to the previous section (chapter 9.x) instead of the Bibliography.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}            
\usepackage{rotating}  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  
\usepackage{bbding}  
\usepackage{framed}  
\usepackage[scriptsize]{caption} 
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{+1.3 cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-1.3 cm}

\linespread{1.1}


\renewcommand{\captionfont}{\normalfont \sffamily \itshape \small}

\newcommand{\checklist}[1]{\vspace{1cm}\begin{framed}
\noindent \textbf{Checklist} #1\end{framed}}

\newcommand{\note}[2]{\begin{framed}\sffamily\small
\noindent \textbf{#1} \\ #2\end{framed}}

\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\include{cover_page}
\thispagestyle{empty} \normalfont 

\clearpage
\include{dedication}

\thispagestyle{empty}  \cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\include{abstract}

\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{.75truecm} \cleardoublepage
\include{acknowledgements}

\thispagestyle{empty} \vspace*{.75truecm} \normalfont \cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{plain}\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}} 
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}         
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}    

\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}    
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}     
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.3pt} 

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}


\include{chapter1/chapter}
\include{chapter2/chapter}
\include{chapter3/chapter}
\include{chapter4/chapter}
\include{chapter5/chapter}
\include{chapter6/chapter}
\include{chapter7/chapter}
\include{chapter8/chapter}
\include{chapter9/chapter}

\cleardoublepage


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{mendeley_v2}
\bibliographystyle{plain}


\cleardoublepage

\appendix

\include{appendixA/appendix}
\include{appendixB/appendix}
\include{appendixC/appendix}

\end{document}
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated!

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) in report `\bibliography` (though the `thebibliography` environment) issues a `\chapter*` which includes a `\clearpage`, thus your `\addcontentsline` is executed on the wrong page. Consider using the `tocbibind` package instead, it is specifically made to solve this problem. BTW: it is recommened to load `hyperref` last as it has to alter a lot of macros.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In report `\bibliography` (through its use of the `thebibliography` environment) issues a `\chapter*{\bibname}`. But first it it runs `\clearpage` or `\cleardouble` page.

Therefore

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliography{mendeley_v2}
```

may end up giving the wrong page numbers/bookmark target.

Often this can be fixed by issuing a `\clearpage` before `\addcontentsline` but this might not work, especially if `hyperref` is involved.

There is a better solution: use the `tocbibind` package as (as in tableofcontents, bibliography, index) it will add these to the TOC and contains various tools to control this.

Therefore use the `tocbibind` package and remove the `\addcontentsline` line to get a much less cluttered code.